# Where is the best place to put "Assumptions" against an element in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

This may be a really dumb question, but I'm trying to get all my spec detail into the model, and while there are requirement and constraints for every element, I can't see a good place to record assumptions.

My current thought is to define them as a new type of constraint (which I guess they are).

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: If the constraints and assumptions are on the requirements themselves, it's probably better to model the requirements explicitly as separate elements. You can make your current requirements external in the properties dialog, but note that you can't change them back, ever. This is because external requirements have more information, such as constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps joining the discussion too late; however...

You have to look at this as a systems engineering issue, rather than a modelling one.  Each assumption in real terms will generate constraints, requirements and probably objects of their own, so it is important to be able to track these through the model and design logic.

To that end, my personal approach would be to create them as stereotypes as Uffe has suggested.  That way you have a tangible object to track and to justify the additional artefacts that will appear (why certain design decisions were made, why a particular interaction takes place, and so forth).

Ideally your assumptions will start to die out as you gain more clarity regarding the problem space and the proposed solution itself.  Whether you then delete these, or set their status in the tool to some value is up to your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your assumptions are re-usable or not.

If not re-usable then your idea of setting up as a type of constraint seems fine.

If you need to be able to re-use them you'll have to use something external to the elements. In that case I would probably create a new stereotype `<<assumption>>` for.

Then you can have multiple elements that have a relation with an `<<assumption>>`

Answer (score 0):

I would not go that far as Geert. An assumption is something temporal and should go away (the sooner the better). Your model should reflect facts, not assumptions. So I would rather place Note elements where you have some "assumption".

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with tagged values, since I don't think assumptions qualify as a type of constraint.

You can create multiple tagged values with the same name ("assumption"), but you may need to change the EA setting `Tools/Options/Objects/Show Duplicate Tags` (middle right) to see them all.

Tags, as opposed to constraints, are also (implicitly) inherited, and can be shown as such in diagrams.